# Android: how to call Instagram app by Intent and show images with filter by tag

Tags: android, android-intent, instagram

I'm looking for an possibility to call the Instagam application with `Intent` (like a Camera: `Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);`) and pass to an external application a filter's `tag`, (as example tag `#orchi`).

Something similar to iphone hooks: http://instagram.com/developer/iphone-hooks/ or this one http://www.gramfeed.com/instagram/tags#orchi

On the official site is described an API but I need a simple solution to show images (filtered by tag) using an external Instagram application.

Comment: It's not possible. I'm trying the same as you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19258217/send-text-tag-to-instagram-using-my-android-app

Comment: yeah, now i know this. may be in the future it might be changed